# Maven / plugin : force fail is some jars are available in the dependency tree

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am looking for a Maven 3 plugin checking (and force compilation error) if some jars are available in the dependency tree.

The idea is to prevent from having some jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder (in my case, more than one SLF4J binding)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need the [`maven-enforcer-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/).

Its set of rules includes a rule to ban specific dependencies from your project. It's the "[Banned Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html)" rule.

Here's a sample plugin configuration from their docs:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <bannedDependencies>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org.apache.maven</exclude>
                    <exclude>org.apache.maven:badArtifact</exclude>
                    <exclude>*:badArtifact</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  <includes>
                    <!--only 1.0 of badArtifact is allowed-->
                    <include>org.apache.maven:badArtifact:1.0</include>
                  </includes>
                </bannedDependencies>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Perfect, it's exactly what I was looking for ! It's possible to enable transitive check with <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>

Comment: Cheers. Be sure to accept this as an answer in that case!

Comment: Ok as soon as I will have enough reputation :)

Comment: Accepting an answer doesn't require reputation, only upvoting/downvoting a post does :)